# Scan hexadecimal floating points in Windows with Linux code

Tags: c, cygwin, mingw, c99

I am trying to compile [Wapiti](http://wapiti.limsi.fr/) 1.3.0 (a NLP tagging tool) in a Windows 8 based machine. The C source code is intended for Linux (and similar) systems. I have managed to compile it using Cygwin gcc. Unfortunately it's not working as it needs to read data from a model file (text file where training information is saved).

It seems that the variable `v` is not being read, in this code line:

```
double v;     
if (fscanf(file, "%"SCNu64"=%la\n", &f, &v) != 2)
```

I guess it is because the Cygwin dll's not being C99 and not being able to use the hex floating points.

I don't think I can compile it with MingW as it requires POSIX system headers, plus I am not sure if MingW handles C99 `fscanf` formatting anyway.

Is there any suggestion of what can I do, or am I missing something?

Thanks for your help!

The program is compiling/working in Linux no problems.